# Why password is not changing?

Tags: django

If I enter incorrect old password, I get message. But if new_pass1 != new_pass2, nothing changes. And if I enter all right, nothing changes too.

**views.py**

```
def change_password(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ChangePassword(request.user, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request, user)
            messages.success(request, 'Your password was successfully updated!')
            return redirect('password_change_done')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Please correct the error below.')
    else:
        form = ChangePassword(request.user)
    return render(request, 'account/password_change.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms.py**

```
class ChangePassword(PasswordChangeForm):
    old_password = forms.CharField(label='', widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control input_pass', 'placeholder': 'Старый пароль'}))
    new_password1 = forms.CharField(label='', widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control input_pass', 'placeholder': 'Новый пароль'}))
    new_password2 = forms.CharField(label='', widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control input_pass', 'placeholder': 'Новый пароль'}))
```

**password_change.html**

```
<form method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ form.as_p }}              
   <button type="submit" name="button" class="btn login_btn">Сменить</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Check if `new_password1` and `new_password2` doesn't have same values so that `is_valid` return true.

Comment: @Charnel form does not pass validation

Comment: Doesn't pass validation but no error message is shown?

Comment: @Charnel shows Please correct the error below. So, it goes to ```else:
            messages.error(request, 'Please correct the error below.')```

Comment: Sorry, I'm now confused - form didn't pass validation, error s shown and password isn't changed. Then what's wrong here?

Comment: @Charnel I have the same question, where is mistake? Why form doesn't pass validation

Comment: Because of `new_pass1 != new_pass2` - both fields should have equal value for validation pass.

Comment: @Charnel but I enter the same new passwords, they should be equal

Comment: When theres no error, does the password change or not?

Comment: @BernardoDuarte doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a `commit` argument to `form.save` like `form.save(commit=True)`.

```
def change_password(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ChangePassword(request.user, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=True)
            update_session_auth_hash(request, user)
            messages.success(request, 'Your password was successfully updated!')
            return redirect('password_change_done')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Please correct the error below.')
    else:
        form = ChangePassword(request.user)
    return render(request, 'account/password_change.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: It didn't help(

Comment: @Elevator The password didn't change?

Comment: The password didn't change. What is more,  form don't pass validation

Comment: @Elevator Have you tried using `PasswordChangeForm` directly? Perhaps the problem is in the way you extended it.

Comment: Tried the same problem. Nothing  changes and password doesn't change too